# How to remove mis-assigned person from iOS 12 photos app on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, photos

In previous iOS versions I could remove mistakenly identified people from photos. This was done by going to the people album, choosing the person that was wrongly assigned, then going to the errorneous photo and tapping on the share button. Then you would have a "not this person" icon. This feature is gone in iOS 12 on the iPad:

[image: iOS12 missing the "not this person" icon]

How do I do this in iOS12 now?